# primefaces dialog disappears after show up

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a commandButton and a dialog. The problem is after the dialog box appears, it disappears(1-2 miliseconds later). Is there a problem with my commandbutton or its dialog issue?

```
<p:commandButton id="showDetailsButton"
     title="Details"
     onclick="details.show();"
     process="@this"
     update=":tabView:myForm:myDialogId"                                         
     icon="ui-icon-search">                          
</p:commandButton>


<p:dialog id="myDialogId"
      header="Details"
      widgetVar="details"
      resizable="false"
      height="600"
      width="450"                  
      >
//some stuff
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Please read @BalusC's comments on my answer. You need to provide more details in the question!

Answer (score 10):

Changed onclick to oncomplete and now It's working perfectly.

```
<p:commandButton id="showDetailsButton"
 title="Details"
 oncomplete="details.show();"
 process="@this"
 update=":tabView:myForm:myDialogId"                                         
 icon="ui-icon-search">
```

Answer (score 3):

By default a `<p:commandButton>` is rendered as

```
<button type="submit" ....> ... </button>
```

**EDIT:**  **Iff**  you've disabled `ajax` behavior by specifying `ajax=false`, please read comments below.

and hence it will trigger a [Post Back](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postback). So your page makes a `POST` request to server and refreshes.

Btw, you don't need a PrimeFaces commandButton here, simply use

```
<input type="button" onclick="details.show()" value="Details"/>
```

Comment: I believe the OP's code is incomplete. The dialog will only disappear if the OP used `ajax="false"` or `update="someIdCoveringDialog"` or so. However, the current code doesn't do that. Perhaps the OP forgot the `<h:form>`. The browser behavior is then unspecified.

Comment: Oops! @BalusC you're right. I missed the default ajax behavior of command button. And yes, if the container itself is updating the dialog would disappear. So overall,I agree that the question is missing details!

Comment: It is clearly is in his question that there is an update (scroll to the right                 process="@this"                                         update=":tabView:myForm:myDialogId"

Answer (score 0):

remove the process and update from your commandbutton. They refresh the page/section. And you don't want that.

Comment: The `process` attribute doesn't do that and there's already no `update` attribute.

Comment: In his code snippit I see clearly an update statement: update=":tabView:myForm:myDialogId"   (scroll to the right)

Comment: You're right about that @roel. I suppose he does want to update the contents of dialog on click. Perhaps he should update the container inside the dialog and not the dialog itself

Comment: What a bad code snippet, please edit so that I can retract the downvote.

Comment: After all, he clearly want to update the contents of the dialog before showing it (e.g. to show the currently selected item). The solution is then not to remove the `update`. Also, the `process` attribute does not refresh the section at all.

Answer (score 0):

If there is another form you have created inside the form tag, you should make sure that it is outside, because unaware update operations can break the process.